# Python: Using replace function to replace item from string with item from list

Tags: python

I am writing code for a game that takes input from a user and replaces that string input with a slice of code from the original string (old_story) I keep getting this TypeError returned. I want to make it so that my code replaces the replace_this string with the corresponding iteration number in the new_word_list (values were assigned to that list earlier on in the code). Is there any way I can go around this problem? There are multiple replace_this strings, and the same amount of items in the new_word_list. How do I get it so that it runs smoothly? Any advice will be highly appreciated, as the documentation is confusing. I understand this is a very simple problem but I would appreciate any help I can get. This is the error that keeps on returning in IDLE: TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

---

```
import random
old_story = random.choice(open('madlibs.txt').readlines())

new_word_list = [""] #new list where user input will be added to.
end = 0
repetitions = old_story.count('{')
for i in range(repetitions):
    start = old_story.find('{', end) + 1
    end = old_story.find('}', start)
    replace_this = old_story[start:end]
    replace_this = input("Please enter a " + replace_this + ":")
    new_word_list.append(str(replace))

new_story = old_story
for i, replace_this in enumerate(old_story):
    if i > len(new_word_list) - 1:
        break
    new_story = old_story.replace(replace_this, new_word_list[i])

new_story = new_story.strip()
print(new_story)
```

Comment: Is `old_story` a string or a list?

Comment: old_story is a string @mattm

Comment: Just as an example:      old_story = "This is a {word}."

Comment: Yep. old_story is a single line string. new_word_list is just a list of strings that will replace every occurrence of the replace_this string in old_story. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yes. The number of words in the new_word_list matches 100% the number of replace_this strings that occur in the old_story. Sort of like a game of madlibs.

Comment: If you're getting an index error with the solution I have below, then the lengths are not equal. See my most recent edit which includes a safety check.

Comment: Wait...Do you only want to replace the `{word}` strings in the old story?

Comment: Yes I only want to replace the {word} strings in the old story.

Comment: It's fine if you can't answer the question, @PadraicCunningham. I updated the question with my full code, but if you can't help, thanks anyway.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am on here because I needed help understanding something that was of confusion to me. There was absolutely no need for you to delete the answer especially when someone else could have benefited, if I couldn't.

Comment: @user3795395, I have not deleted it yet

Comment: @user3795395 I entered a new answer which I'm pretty sure should accomplish what you're looking for. I tried to explain the what and why of what's going on. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Sorry, I missed the call to `enumerate()`, I've updated and tested the code. It is working as expected now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot pass the list itself, you need to access the item in the list by index:

```
s = "foo foobar foo"
l = ["hello world "]

print s.replace("foobar",l[0])
foo hello world  foo

l = ["hello world ","different string"]

print s.replace("foobar",l[-1])
foo different string foo



old_story =  "This is a {word}."
new_word_list = ["one","two","three","four"]

spl = old_story.split() #  split  into individual words
for ind, new_s in enumerate(new_word_list):
    spl[ind] = new_s # replace element at matching index
print (" ".join(spl)) # rejoin string from updated list
one two three four

old_story =  "This {foo} is {a} {foo} {bar}."
new_word_list = ["is","my","final","solution"]
spl = old_story.split()
for ind, word in enumerate(spl):
    if word.startswith("{"):
         spl[ind] = new_word_list.pop(0)
print (" ".join(spl))
This is is my final solution
```

If you variables you can use them with `str.format`:

```
old_story = " Hello! I {verb} a {noun} today!"

new_word_list = ["is","my","final","solution"]
verb, noun = ["ate","hotdog"]

print( old_story.format(verb=verb,noun=noun))
 Hello! I ate a hotdog today!
```

Comment: I am having trouble making it so that I don't have to hardcode every single change that has to be made. I want my code to be dynamic in it that the for loop will change the replace_this str with the next string on the new_word_list list, up until there are no more words left on the new_word_list list.

Comment: Apologies. Left an example of old_story above.

Comment: I tried and it returned a syntax error in the last line where the quotations are. I've updated the full question with my full code to see if that helps with the solution. Thank you.

Comment: I am using python 3.4

Comment: Please enter a noun:mom
Please enter a verb:run
Please enter a adjective:red
Please enter a noun:boy
['', 'mom', 'run', 'red', 'boy']
one two three four
>>>     (It returns one two three four instead of the new story with the replaced words)

Comment: The code is doing exactly as it says it will do. The thing is, There should be the same number of {words} as there are strings in the new_word_list

Comment: My apologies. I didn't ask the question the correct way. Earlier on in the code above (the one that is shown in the bio of this question) I ask the user for input for the {noun} {verb}, etc. that show up in the old story. The user input is the assigned to the list new_word_list. I just need help on getting the final part done, printing out the new_story with the strings from the new_word_list to replace the replace_this strings in the old_story. Does that make sense? Let me know if I need to clarify.

Comment: example string is old_story = " Hello! I {verb} a {noun} today!"

Comment: expected output would be new_story = "Hello! I ate a hotdog today!"

Comment: @user3795395: Check the most recent edit to my post, I'm pretty sure it should work for what you're trying to do

Comment: @user3795395, added final solution

Comment: @user3795395, I added how to use str.format, if you are using strings like in your example it may be useful